# Add border and corner radius in tableview section content wise

Tags: swift3

Tableview separation by section content wise. Is possible to do that. I have attache a screen shot below. Please help me any one have idea about that. [image]

Comment: not able to view your screenshot.

Comment: You can use each TableViewCell for each UI. Then set height according to content  at run time